# Polymer 3, slot element in template is not filled

Tags: javascript, mathjax, polymer-3.x

I'm trying to make a polymer 3 element, that wraps around the `<math-tex>` [element](https://github.com/janmarthedal/math-tex) defined by Jan Marthedal Rasmussen. Unfortunately I am not able to fill the element with the proper content using the `<slot></slot>` syntax in the template and I have no idea of why.

The new element is defined in the file

tve-inline-equation.js

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer@3.0.0/polymer-element.js';
// import 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/iron-flex-layout@3.0.1/iron-flex-layout-classes.js';

class TVEInlineEquation extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`
<math-tex><slot>0</slot></math-tex>
`;
  }
}

customElements.define('tve-inline-equation', TVEInlineEquation);
```

The element is tested in the document

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
  <head>
    <!-- https://github.com/janmarthedal/math-tex -->
    <script src="math-tex.js"></script>
    <script src="math-tex-controller.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="tve-inline-equation.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>

<p>Place for an inline equation, using my custom html 
element tve-line-equation.</p>
<tve-inline-equation>c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}</tve-inline-equation>
<p>The problem is that the equation is not rendered 
and the "0" from the default slot value is inserted instead.</p>

<p>A new location for an equation, this time directly in
a math-tex element.</p>
<math-tex>c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}</math-tex>

</body>
</html>
```

An online playground with the code is available at [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/71LRctpGIPliXX0M2xgC?p=preview).

An additional thing that bother me is that when the iron-flex-layout is imported, the textual representation of the equation is showed on the screen instead of the default content of the slot.

Comment: try to type `import './math-tex.js'` into `tve-inline-equation.js`  Its renders but I think not like you wanted . :  `c = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}`